# Erlang : Why operation on Lists are fastest with recursivity + reverse instead of map?

Tags: erlang

I was quite curious what was the speedest way to do operations on an List.

I have created a little module to help me figure this out :

```
-module(tests).

-compile(export_all).

createRandomList(Nb) ->
    [random:uniform(10) || _ <- lists:seq(1, Nb)].

fastest() ->
    List = createRandomList(10000),
    StartFlatten = tools:getTimeStampMilli(),
    flatten(List),
    StopFlatten = tools:getTimeStampMilli(),
    debug:print("Flatten~n"),
    debug:print("Start at: ~p~nStop at: ~p~nTime elapsed: ~p~n", [StartFlatten, StopFlatten, (StopFlatten-StartFlatten)]),
    debug:print("#############~n~n"),
    StartReverse = tools:getTimeStampMilli(),
    reverse(List),
    StopReverse = tools:getTimeStampMilli(),
    debug:print("Reverse~n"),
    debug:print("Start at: ~p~nStop at: ~p~nTime elapsed: ~p~n", [StartReverse, StopReverse, (StopReverse-StartReverse)]),
    debug:print("#############~n~n"),
    StartMap = tools:getTimeStampMilli(),
    map(List),
    StopMap = tools:getTimeStampMilli(),
    debug:print("Map~n"),
    debug:print("Start at: ~p~nStop at: ~p~nTime elapsed: ~p~n", [StartMap, StopMap, (StopMap-StartMap)]),
    debug:print("#############~n~n").

op(A) ->
    A+2.

flatten(List) ->
    flatten(List, []).
flatten([], Accu) ->
    Accu;
flatten([Obj|Tail], Accu) ->
    flatten(Tail, lists:flatten([Accu, op(Obj)])).

reverse(List) ->
    reverse(List, []).
reverse([], Accu) ->
    lists:reverse(Accu);
reverse([Obj|Tail], Accu) ->
    reverse(Tail, [op(Obj)|Accu]).

map(List) ->
    lists:map(fun op/1, List).
```

And Here's are the result :

```
----debug: Flatten
Start at: 1424535074364
Stop at: 1424535274083
Time elapsed: 1.99719 s
----debug: #############

----debug: Reverse
Start at: 1424535274208
Stop at: 1424535274551
Time elapsed: 0.00343 s
----debug: #############

----debug: Map
Start at: 1424535274631
Stop at: 1424535275095
Time elapsed: 0.00464 s
----debug: #############
```

I can actually get why using the flatten method is waaaay longer than others... but I would consider that a function that is made for operations on Lists would be faster than my own recursive function with a reverse...

Anyone have an explanation ?

**Or I might just have an ugly bug in my module !!**

EDIT1 : 
Here's what I get if I call the test again and again on bigger List :

```
3> tests:fastest().
----debug: Reverse
Start at: 1424536230201935
Stop at: 1424536230262924
Time elapsed: 60989
----debug: #############

----debug: Map
Start at: 1424536230263066
Stop at: 1424536230326419
Time elapsed: 63353
----debug: #############

ok
4> tests:fastest().
----debug: Reverse
Start at: 1424536231860951
Stop at: 1424536231917979
Time elapsed: 57028
----debug: #############

----debug: Map
Start at: 1424536231918116
Stop at: 1424536231975828
Time elapsed: 57712
----debug: #############

ok
5> tests:fastest().
----debug: Reverse
Start at: 1424536233253424
Stop at: 1424536233309301
Time elapsed: 55877
----debug: #############

----debug: Map
Start at: 1424536233309430
Stop at: 1424536233375391
Time elapsed: 65961
----debug: #############

ok
6> tests:fastest().
----debug: Reverse
Start at: 1424536235622322
Stop at: 1424536235675287
Time elapsed: 52965
----debug: #############

----debug: Map
Start at: 1424536235675424
Stop at: 1424536235739555
Time elapsed: 64131
----debug: #############
```

Weird, no ?

EDIT2 :

Ok Managed to use timer:tc here's the result :

```
1> tests:fastest().
ReverseTime: 58455
MapTime: 47507
ok
2> tests:fastest().
ReverseTime: 29887
MapTime: 61311
ok
3> tests:fastest().
ReverseTime: 61563
MapTime: 68040
ok
4> tests:fastest().
ReverseTime: 55874
MapTime: 57388
ok
5> tests:fastest().
ReverseTime: 56712
MapTime: 61326
ok
```

Kinda the same as before...

Comment: These aren't arrays, they're lists. Erlang has an [array type](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/array.html) that's not a list, so your question is confusing.

Comment: You might want to look into the [`timer:tc/1,2,3` functions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#tc-1) for timing function calls.

Comment: Managed to use timer:tc finally, but it does not change the overall results... there is no winner between the 2

Comment: Did you have a look at the implementation of map/2 in the lists module? `map(F, [H|T]) ->
    [F(H)|map(F, T)];
map(F, []) when is_function(F, 1) -> [].` It seems normal that you get the same performances :o)

Comment: Actually I though map was a BIF, didn't even tried to check out the implementation, thanks @Pascal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pascal observes in the comments to your question, the implementation of `lists:map/2` in the Erlang standard library constructs a new list head to tail in the exact order they appear in the original list. Your "reverse" function constructs it in the opposite order, or tail-to-head.

One of the side effects of head-to-tail ordering is that the virtual machine must *return the result* from each call to the map function to the function that called it. That is to say, each call to the function adds another *return address* to the *call stack* that must be visited once the final call has been completed in order to produce the ultimate return value. You can see this in the syntax of the call itself:

```
map(F, [H|T]) ->
    %% At this point, the result of map(F, T) is unknown,
    %% so we must evaluate it to determine what the tail
    %% of this expression should be.
    [F(H)|map(F, T)];
map(F, []) ->
    [].
```

On the other side, tail-to-head ordering can be optimized for *tail recursion*, meaning that the original stack is *reused* for all subsequent calls. This effectively optimizes away all of those return addresses we have to visit when building the list the other way around. Indeed, if you were to remove your call to `lists:reverse/1`, you would see the tail-to-head ordering outperform the head-to-tail ordering even more consistently.

```
reverse(F, [H|T], Acc) ->
    %% Here, we know what Acc is, so the only thing
    %% we have to evaluate is F(H). 
    %% And since we're calling ourselves recursively and
    %% do nothing with the return value of the function, 
    %% we're eligible for tail-call optimization.
    reverse(F, T, [F(H)|Acc]);
reverse(F, [], Acc) ->
    %% Now we launch into another function that's eligible
    %% for tail-call optimization (though its implementation
    %% uses another form of stack sharing, known as a "while
    %% loop"
    lists:reverse(Acc).
```

Finally, `lists:reverse/1` is a C-optimized BIF that can execute a hell of a lot faster than any equivalent pure-Erlang function (achieved by bypassing the BEAM interpreter and some smart allocation hacks). Even without that consideration, though, reversing is another tail-recursive operation that doesn't require visiting various return points, made even more efficient by virtue of the fact that Erlang makes *shallow copies* of the terms from the original list (basically using a pointer/reference to the term instead of a new copy of the term itself).